# PHP laravel save() function with 2 param not updating records

Tags: php, laravel

```
$storeUpdate = $this->myModel->save($data, $idData);
```

hey i have code like above, when i tried to update data with save function my records not updating
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, find the model you want to update then update the model. (simple)

```
$model = $this->myModel->find($idData);
$model->update($data);
```

or
If the data or id is not already exist you can use `firstOrCreate`

```
$model = $this->myModel->firstOrCreate($data);
```

hopes it can help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `save` method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` takes an array of options, if you were to pass anything at all, not attributes to set on the model or an `id` to find. It saves the current model instance whether insert or update.

You could find the model by primary key then call `update` on that instance:

```
$model = $this->myModel->findOrFail($id);
$ret = $model->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

read the document here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates

```
$storeUpdate = $this->myModel->find($idData);
$storeUpdate->your_field_1=$your_value_1;
$storeUpdate->your_field_2=$your_value_2;
$storeUpdate->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To update a model, you should retrieve it and set attributes you wish to update, and then call the save method, as below

```
$model= App\ModelName::find($id);

$model->attributeName= 'AttributeValue';

$model->save();
```

In your case you can mass update as below

```
$model= App\ModelName::find($id);
$model->update($data);
```

For more information you can see laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates)

Answer (score 0):

```
return tap(ModelName::findOrFail($id))->update($data);

* $data: make sure your data is up to date from your view.
* tap method on collections which allow you to “tap” into the collection at a specific point and do something with the results while not affecting the main collection.

Any question feel free for asking me!
```